# How to get data from a different sheet based one the adjacent sheet in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

How would I change the sheet name in B3 when the name is changed in A3?

Could someone please assist me with this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Given the range and examples in your post, try this:

`=INDIRECT(A3&"!A1")`